# Creating a Movie (or SlideShow) with some Music

Tags: windows, video, photos, slideshow, pictures

I want to create a movie or slide show of some pictures and while playing the slide show or that movie I would like to embed few music files. For example I could then burn those pictures as an Album on a CD and when playing the CD to view images would also run that music.

I saw something like this on my friend's Mac (Powerbook or something)

How to accomplish this in Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download Windows Live Gallery and MovieMaker.  Point it to the pictures and then browse to the music file.  Hit the burn button and voila.